# Adding spaces at specific positions in a numeric string

Tags: php, regex, numbers, preg-replace, spaces

I would like to add spaces between set of numbers with `preg_replace()`;

`$numbers = '90000800123987';`

Desired output: `900 00 800 123 987`

I'm quite confused at this point, I couldn't get the desired output so far.

Comment: How do you determine where the spaces go?  It sounds more like you have a preconceived notion of where the spaces should go, in which case `substr` (string splitting) would be a better choice.  A regex engine is serious overkill/overhead especially considering you're not replacing anything.

Comment: You are right, just did it with `substr`. Regex would be just 1 line of code though. It will just look more clear to the eye.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your concrete example this would do it:

```
$numbers = '90000800123987';
$regex = '/(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})/';
$result = preg_replace($regex, '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5', $numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but can be refined.

```
preg_replace(
    '/^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})$/',
    '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5',
    $numbers
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding @splash's answer, the extra backslashes are not necessary and the first  and fifth capture groups can be omited (only the middle three need to be transferred to the replacement string and spaces would be written at the start and end), so the answer can be boiled down to:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5tXmp))

```
var_export(
    preg_replace('/\d{3}\K(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})/', ' $1 $2 $3 ', '90000800123987')
);
output: '900 00 800 123 987'
```

This matches the first 3 characters, then forgets them, them captures the next 2 characters (`$1`), then the next 3 characters (`$2`), then the next 3 characters (`$3`).

---

As an academic indulgence, this task can also be done without any capture groups or references in your replacement string.

Find the zero-width position after the 3rd, 5th, 8th, and 11th digits then add a space at these positions.

- The 4th&5th digits are followed by 9 digits and the end of the string.
- The other targeted 3-digit strings are not at the end of the string.
- `\K` means forget what is currently matched - so no characters are actually removed in the replacement.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qm46e)) ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YOpHCv/1))

```
var_export(
    preg_replace(
        '~(?|\d{2}(?=\d{9}$)|\d{3}(?!$))\K~',
        ' ',
        '90000800123987'
    )
);
```

Output:

```
'900 00 800 123 987'
```

Other working patterns include:

- ```
  ~(?|(?<=^\d{5})|\d{3}\K(?!$))~
  ```
- ```
  ~(?|\d{2}(?<=^\d{5})|\d{3}(?!$))\K~
  ```
- ```
  ~(?=(?>\d{11}|\d{9}|\d{6}|\d{3})$)~
  ```
- ```
  ~(?<=^\d{3}|^\d{5}|^\d{8}|^\d{11})~
  ```

---

I find non-regex techniques to be less attractive:

```
$s = '90000800123987';
var_export(
    "$s[0]$s[1]$s[2] $s[3]$s[4] $s[5]$s[6]$s[7] $s[8]$s[9]$s[10] $s[11]$s[12]$s[13]"
);
```

or

```
$s = '90000800123987';
var_export(
    substr($s, 0, 3)
    . ' ' . substr($s, 3, 2)
    . ' '. substr($s, 5, 3)
    . ' '. substr($s, 8, 3)
    . ' '. substr($s, 11, 3)
);
```

or

```
var_export(
    substr_replace(
        substr_replace(
            substr_replace(
                substr_replace(
                    '90000800123987',
                    ' ',
                    11,
                    0
                ),
                ' ',
                8,
                0
            ),
            ' ',
            5,
            0
        ),
        ' ',
        3,
        0
    )
);
```